# fix x-axis of the vuejs bar chart

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In my vuejs laravel application I'm trying to implement a bar chart using apexcharts module.

```
<apexchart ref="apexChart" :options="chartOptions" :series="chartData" type="bar"></apexchart>
```

Following is my `<sctipt></script>`

```
<script>
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            daywise_sales: [],
            chartData: [],
            mostSellingDay: '',
            leastSellingDay: '',
            chartOptions: {
                xaxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yaxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: "Sales"
                    }
                },
                chart: {
                    id: 'daywise_sales'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Day wise sales'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/shopify-day-wise-sales')
        .then(response => {
            this.daywise_sales = response.data.day_totals;
            this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = Object.keys(this.daywise_sales)
            .map(date => {
              return new Date(date).toLocaleString('default', {weekday: 'long'});
            });
            // Ensure that the chartData property is correctly set with the data
            this.chartData = [{data: Object.values(this.daywise_sales)}];
            
            // Find the most and least selling days
            let mostSellingDay = '';
            let mostSellingDaySales = 0;
            let leastSellingDay = '';
            let leastSellingDaySales = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
            for (let date in this.daywise_sales) {
                if (this.daywise_sales[date] > mostSellingDaySales) {
                    mostSellingDay = date;
                    mostSellingDaySales = this.daywise_sales[date];
                }
                if (this.daywise_sales[date] < leastSellingDaySales) {
                    leastSellingDay = date;
                    leastSellingDaySales = this.daywise_sales[date];
                }
            }
            this.mostSellingDay = new Date(mostSellingDay).toLocaleString('default', {weekday: 'long'});
            this.leastSellingDay = new Date(leastSellingDay).toLocaleString('default', {weekday: 'long'});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

From my back end for the  `response.data.day_totals` i get following array

```
array:8 [
  "2023-01-11" => 1
  "2023-01-09" => 1
  "2023-01-05" => 0
  "2023-01-06" => 0
  "2023-01-07" => 0
  "2023-01-08" => 0
  "2023-01-10" => 0
  "2023-01-12" => 0
]
```

Issue is I need to set the dates in short names (Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue...etc) instead of 1,2... for the xaxis and for the yaxis the number of sales per each day...

This is my current chart.

[image]

How can I fix my x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this part of doc https://apexcharts.com/docs/formatting-axes-labels/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).